# jquery; how to force element to redraw in a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, redraw

I want to write my own jquery plugin to apply an effect to an element.
The effect is to collapse a html element (I'm sure these already exist but I want to learn to write my own).

The function gets the width of the selected element and reduces its width; e.g.

```js
var width = $(this).width();  // get width
   
while(width > 0){
    width -= 1;
    $(this).width(width);  // set new width .... but element it not redrawn
```

The problem I have is that I do not see the width gradually reduced but element is redrawn once width is 0 i.e. once the loop has been executed and probably when the function returns.

How can I get the element to be redrawn so that I can see the width shrink?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is not delay in your loop.

The loop is executed in a few microseconds, that is why you can't see your element being redrawn.

You could use `setTimeout` to delay the execution of the loop, and call it back for each iteration until the element width is 0 :

```
function reduceWidth(item) {
    item.width(item.width() - 1);
    if (item.width() > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            reduceWidth(item);
        }, 1);
    }
}
reduceWidth($('#your_element'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of your code, where the browser will re-render inbetween each loop:

```
TIMEOUT_MS = 10;
var $element = $(this);

var width = $element.width();

function resize() {
    $element.width(--width);
    if(!width) return;
    setTimeout(resize, TIMEOUT_MS);
}

resize();
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm81qav3/2/)

As you can see, I have replaced the `while` loop with a recursive call to `resize()`.

Here is an explanation:

Browsers only redraw the screen between so-called "run loops." A "run-loop" is a block of synchronous code - meaning "without breaks". The `while` loop which you posted is a such a segment of synchronous (read "blocking") code. In other words, it does not have any "breaks" in itself that allow the browser to redraw.

If you want the browser to draw intermediate steps, you have to defer execution into the next "run loop". (You have to put pauses into the execution)

There are two relevant methods that do this: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). `setTimeout` will defer the execution of a method into a future run-loop, while `setInterval` will do so repetitively.

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer and explanation - I was aware I needed to break out of the loop and did start looking at setInterval/setTimeout